# Mobile Application Emulator options

Tags: angularjs, html, testing, emulation, mobile-application

we are developing HTML5 Mobile application (with angular + kendo controls). we are looking for emulator options to test our application in different devices (mainly tablets - samsung/ipad/ms surface) and its browsers (chrome,safari,ie, and its native browsers). Got to know about saucelabs and browserstack in which we can test our application in different device / os combinations, but it looks like our application has to be hosted in cloud?..(it seems to me they are more of testing tool than a dev tool ). we are looking for emulator - which helps the developer (how the application will be rendered in that device, not just the resolution) to test in multiple os/device environments before moving it to 'test'. Any suggestion?

Comment: use android studio

Comment: please note that the application is also for desktop and then for tablets (such as samsung, surface and also ipad.) with different browsers.